# Open more than one dataset with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function

I would like to implement a function which is able to open more than one dataset at the same time. Dataseth path and names would be passed as argument of the function (path as optional).Datasets are within the same directory and can have different extensions (csv, json and sql) so I can't choose before what of the "xxx" methods I would have to use (.read_csv, .read_json o .read_sql). If l is a list where I have the name of the datasets, for instance:

```
l = [d1.csv, d2.json]
```

I think something like the following, syntactically and semantically wrong:

```
df = []
ext = [".json",".csv",".sql"]
```

```
def fun(path, l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if "condition on names of l[i] and files on path is TRUE": #controls if the file is within the path
            for j in range(len(ext)):
                if "condition on "ext" is TRUE": #controls the extension of the file
                    df [i] = pandas.read_ext[j](path, l[i])
    return df
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
ext_to_fn = {
    ".csv": pd.read_csv,
    ".json": pd.read_json,
    ".xls": pd.read_excel,
}


def pd_open(basename, **kwargs):
    for ext, fn in ext_to_fn.items():
        filename = basename + ext
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            return fn(filename, **kwargs)
    raise ValueError('No file/loader matching %s' % basename)
```

It will try each of the known extensions and loaders:

```
d1 = pd_open("d1")  # tries d1.json, d1.csv, d1.xls
d2 = pd_open("d2")  # etc.
```

You can also pass any kwargs that are supported by all of the loaders, e.g. `dtype` and so on.

Comment: AKX, I found the following error because in my case actually "basename" is a list:
     59     for ext, fn in ext_to_fn.items():
---> 60       filename = basename + etx
     61         if os.path.isfile(filename):
     62             return f(file_name)

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: I tried to insert a for cycle [for i in range(len(basename)):] before/after yours so I can indicate basename[i].. it seems working but it raises the ValueError even though the file is actually in the file path.. any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have some similar function to AKX, in Databricks that invokes a stored procedure in SQL to gather various metadata :

you can use `Path.(..).is_file` to write some error handling.

`r.glob` will trawl child directories.

```
from pathlib import Path
def open_variable_files(parent_path, child_paths=False):
    reader_dict = {
        ".txt": pd.read_csv,
        ".csv": pd.read_csv,
        ".json": pd.read_json,
        ".xlsx": pd.read_excel,
        '.sql'  : pd.read_sql

    }
    if child_paths == False:
        return {f.name: reader_dict[f.suffix](f) for f in Path(parent_path).glob("*")}
    elif child_paths == True:
        return {f.name: reader_dict[f.suffix](f) for f in Path(parent_path).rglob("*")}


variable_files = open_variable_files(path_to_files,child_paths=False)

for k,v in variable_files.items():
    print(k,v.head(1))


File20200610.csv    Unnamed: 0  e  f
0           0  0  0
File20201012.json   Unnamed: 0  c  d
0           0  0  0
File20201012.sql    Unnamed: 0  c  d
0           0  0  0
File20201012.txt    Unnamed: 0  c  d
0           0  0  0
output.xlsx    a
0  1
```